# Can't connect to realm object server when run on device

Tags: swift, realm

I have an issue when connect to Realm Object Server on my device but it works on simulator.
it's return errors :

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." 
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170255450 {Error 
Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo=
{_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://127.0.0.1:9080/auth, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:9080/auth, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the 
server.}): file 
/Users/tungvu/Desktop/Swift3Xcode8/RealmTask/RealmTask/ViewController.swift, 
line 57
```

Here's my connect to Realm Object Server function:

```
SyncUser.logIn(with: .usernamePassword(username: username, password: password, register: false), server: URL(string : "http://127.0.0.1:9080")!) { (user, error) in
        guard let user = user else {
            fatalError(String(describing: error))
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Open Realm
            let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
                syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://127.0.0.1:9080/~/realmtasks")!)
            )
```

Comment: Did you check internet connectivity on the device? Can you browse in the browser?

Comment: No problem with network connection

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, you're using the localhost IP address `127.0.0.1`. While this will work with apps running on the same device as the Realm Object Server instance (ie the iOS Simulator), you'll need the actual IP address of the machine on the local network in order to connect from a separate device like an iPhone.

The easiest way to find the network IP address is to hold down Alt, and then click on the Wi-Fi icon in the macOS status bar:

[image: Wi-Fi IP Address]

If you replace `127.0.0.1` with your Mac's network IP address, other devices should then be able to connect to it. This should work for the iOS Simulator as well, so there shouldn't be a need to change it until your machine's IP address changes.

Comment: Sir, Please can you briefly explained this **If you replace 127.0.0.1 with your Mac's network IP address, other devices should then be able to connect to it. This should work for the iOS Simulator as well, so there shouldn't be a need to change it until your machine's IP address changes**

Comment: Woah. It's been a while since I wrote this. What I meant was that the IP address they were trying to connect with was the localhost IP address for that computer, which is why the Simulator was still able to work. The localhost address doesn't work when a separate device on the network needs to find that particular computer. In that case, they actually need to work out what the private IP address of the computer on the network is, and use that one instead. I hope that helped!